# How can I know the row of char/string in a CSV file

Tags: c, file

For example, I have a CSV file:

```
1 ,2 ,3 ,4
5 ,6 ,7 ,8
a ,b ,c ,d
e ,f ,g ,h
```

and I want to know which row contains the char 'c'.
How can I know it?
i
below its my code

```
FILE* srcFile = fopen(argv[ONE], "r");

char str[MAX_LETTERS] = { 0 };
char letter = ' ';
char copy = ZERO;
int count = 1;

fgets(str, MAX_LETTERS, stdin);
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] == ZERO;
copy = fgetc(srcFile);
while (copy != EOF)
{
    if (copy == str)
    {
        printf("find %d", count);
        break;
    }
    else if (copy == "\n")
    {
        printf("nextLine");
        count++;
    }
    copy = fgetc(srcFile);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, if so, please provide a [mcve] along with a short explanation of what was wrong. SO is a Q&A site, not a code writing service.

Comment: `char copy = ZERO;` --> `int copy = ZERO;` Changes to compare with `EOF`.  `copy == "\n"` --> `copy == '\n'` CString to character.  `copy == str` --> `copy == *str` For the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are reading the file line by line, you could just create a counter and for every line read in increment the counter by one. If you are reading in character by character you can count the number of newlines.

Comment: But how can i compare between them? its give me the error
q4.c:143: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Edited

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Edited

Answer (score 0):

The double equals signs `==` in C are used for comparison, a single equals sign is for assignment.

It appears the line,
`str[strcspn(str, "\n")] == ZERO;`
is doing a comparison instead of setting the character at the given index of the str array to ZERO.

Change this to a single equals sign if you are trying to terminate your string at the newline character.